# "Subscript out of range" working with arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Probably it is a silly question and relatively simple to solve, but I am not used to working with Excel VBA, thus, I don't get what is wrong with my approach to assigning array element values.

```
Sub Data()
    Dim a As String
    Dim dt_array(), dt_date(), dt_time() As Variant
    dt_array = Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A290").Value
    Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A290") = dt_array()
    a = dt_array(1)
    For i = 1 To 289 Step 1
        dt_date(i) = dt_array(i)
        dt_date(i) = Left(dt_array(i), 10)
        Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2" + i) = dt_date(i)
        dt_time(i) = Left(dt_array(i), 8)
        Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2" + i) = dt_time(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The problem starts already in row 6 `a = dt_array(1)` where I tried to figure out why `dt_date(i) = dt_array(i)` doesn't work.

Can you please help me with that?

I still have a huge problem, basically, it keeps running and doesn't show the content of variables or it displays it totally wrong. Honestly, I don't even understand what is wrong, it just doesn't show anything which indicates on mistake.
My code looks like that now:

```
Sub Data()
    Dim a As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dt_array(), dt_date(1 To 289), dt_time(1 To 289) As Variant
    dt_array = Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A290").Value
    'Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A290") = dt_array()
    a = dt_array(3, 1)
    For i = 1 To 288
        'dt_date(i) = dt_array(i, 1)
        dt_date(i) = Left(dt_array(i, 1), 10)
        dt_time(i) = Right(dt_array(i, 1), 8)
    Next i
Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A290") = dt_date()
Workbooks("Smacro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B290") = dt_time()
End Sub
```

Comment: `dt_array(1,i)` an array made from a range has two dimensions.

Comment: When you read data from Excel into an array, the array is always 2-dimensional, even if you read the data only from 1 row or 1 column. So you need to write `dt_array(1, 1)`

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue for the parameter a, but in some reason I keeping receiving the error for: `dt_date(1, i) = Left(dt_array(1, i), 10)`

Comment: should be `(i,1)` if you turn on your locals window you can inspect the array and see this

Comment: You need to declare your output arrays also as 2-dimension arrays, eg `dt_date(1 To 289, 1 to 1)`